# Drupal for Facebook logout problem

Tags: social-network

I can connect through this module, but i can't logout. I don't know how, but it doesn't clear the cache or something else. It still remembers my account details and relogin me again everytime.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you should log out of your facebook account and then try the same.

It would surely work fine.

Comment: of course. but you know... users will go to facebook and then logout here :) not good

Comment: then you could add a dashboard for the authenticated user.

Comment: a dashboard with what? logout links?

Comment: Add a user menu which is provided by drupal. 
User menu has the logout link.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a menu there.

Drupal provides you a **user menu** which has logout link.